# Timer is trying to convert to String

Tags: java, swing, timer, javax.swing.timer

Can someone please tell me why the Timer is trying to Convert an int into a String. Here is the error that keeps coming up.

> CurrentTimePrinter.java:48: error: incompatible types: int cannot be
>   converted to String
>         time = new Timer(1000,listener);
>
> CurrentTimePrinter.java:49: error: cannot find symbol
>         time.start();

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;

public class CurrentTimePrinter extends JFrame 
{
   private JButton Exitbutton;
   private JTextField textField;
   private static final int FIELD_WIDTH = 10;
   private static final int FRAME_WIDTH = 600;
   private static final int FRAME_HEIGHT = 400;
   private ActionListener listener;
   public Timer time;

   public CurrentTimePrinter()
   {
      //listener = new CtpListener();
      createComponents();
      setSize(FRAME_WIDTH, FRAME_HEIGHT);
   }
   public void createComponents()
   {
      Color orange = new Color(255,165,0);
      Font font = new Font("Times New Roman", Font.BOLD, 14);      
      textField = new JTextField(FIELD_WIDTH);
      Exitbutton = new JButton("EXIT");
      class CtpListener implements ActionListener
      {   
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
         {
            textField.setText("" + new Date());
            Date now = new Date();
            System.out.println(now);
         }
      } 
      ActionListener listener = new CtpListener();
      time = new Timer(1000,listener);
      time.start();


      Exitbutton.setFont(font);
      Exitbutton.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
      ExitButtonListener exitListener = new ExitButtonListener();
      Exitbutton.addActionListener(exitListener);
      JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
      time = new Timer(1000, listener); 
      time.start();

      JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();
      panel1.setBackground(orange);
      panel1.add(Exitbutton);
      panel2.add(textField);
      JPanel contentPane = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
      contentPane.add(panel1, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
      contentPane.add(panel2, BorderLayout.CENTER);
      setContentPane(contentPane);
   }  
   class ExitButtonListener implements ActionListener
   {
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
      {
         System.exit(0);
      }
   }            

   public static void main(String[] args)
   {     
      JFrame frame = new CurrentTimePrinter();
      frame.setTitle("Current Time");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using `java.util.Timer`. You want `javax.swing.Timer` here.

Replace that in the imports, it should be:

```
 import javax.swing.Timer;
```

Comment: That's all it was! Thanks very much!